# How to receive bytes in Managed C++ project from COM plus project

Tags: com, com-interop

I have a module A in Managed C++, it depends on module B in native C++ which wrapped as COM plus.
In module B, I read bytes from a file. Now I am trying to call the file reading functionality from A. But failed.

Dependency detail: I used tlbimp.exe and generated the interop according to Module B. A referrs to the interop.

I tried to pass an "array^" but only one char was received, which is understandable because marshaling doesn't know the array length and could NOT handle the whole array.

I searched out some recommendation about safe array, but could NOT use it successfully in my projects.
Could somebody help me on this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could use IStream instead of passing bytes.

Comment: So I need to implement IStream in module B and export it to A?
And create stream object in module A with the exported type from B?

Comment: Something like that. You can even reuse the existing .NET IStream built specially for native interop (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.istream.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to be talking to your native object via COM, you're going to have to pass the array the COM way.

`SAFEARRAY` would definitely work, but you don't have to use it. It is a fair amount of work to set up anyway. If neither component is a scripting language or VB6, there is little value to using a `SAFEARAY`.

COM can marshal the array just fine, you just have to tell it how big it is. The two most common mechanisms in COM to pass (native) arrays are "fixed-sized arrays" and "conformant arrays".

- [Fixed-size array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373881%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

If you know at compile time the size of the array, this is the way to go. Declare your COM method as follows in your IDL:

```
...
const long ARRAY_SIZE = 1024;
...
HRESULTS MethodAbc(MyClass array[ARRAY_SIZE]);
```

Marshalling will take care of passing the whole array.

- [Conformant Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

You declare them as follows in IDL:

```
HRESULT MethodAbc([size_is(arraySize)] MyClass array[], long arraySize);
```

This tells COM that the arraySize parameter holds the count of elements.

My experience with CLI is minimal, but I don't think you can just pass a CLI handle. Among other things, I believe you need to pin the pointer so that GC doesn't move the array during the COM call. Others please correct me here if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!

I chose "Conformant Arrays" for my arrays, but:
1. You suggestion works if A and B runs in the same process;
2. It doesn't work if A and B runs in different process;

Unfortunately, my module B is in COM+ standard and running in a different process with module A.

What more should I do now to use the way of "Conformant Arrays"? Or I have to choose a new way to handle
the out-of-process case?

Comment: @user2451353, of what type/class is the array? Are you using custom marshaling?

Comment: It's array<unsigned char,1>^, no custom marshaling.

Comment: Unfortunately, tlb doesn't support size_is attribute... But thanks a lot for helping me on this! http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236970

Comment: SAFEARRAY works. So I chose it as the solution, if any performance issue is found, I might turn to IStream, thanks for your kind help!